# Android Application Font rendering

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have faced an issue when supporting Indian fonts in Android Application. If I am Add custom font as resource some fonts will shifted it location. But I need to fixed that problem.

Is there any way to solve that problem. It is possible fixed it with Android NDK?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Check out this](https://github.com/mayooresan/Japs-Attack-Ceylon--Android-App) project for rendering custom font in web view.
2. Check out [this](https://github.com/mayooresan/Android-Tamil) & [this](https://github.com/mayooresan/android-tamilvisai/tree/master/tamilvisai) project for rendering custom font in text view

Comment: Thank you, But I think i need some class similar to UnicodeUtils for replacing Malayalam Unicode like , text = text.replace("ஸ்ரீ", "="); text = text.replace(",", ">");. Let me know if similar projects  available in malayalam.

Comment: as mention the first link's project is using webview to display custom font, and for that html file placed in asset folder, you can embed your data in that html file runtime and later on you can use that html to show in webview

Comment: Yes, I am doing it already, And it displays the text. The problem is "KOOTAKSHARAM" (complex/combined letters) in Malayalam language is displaying as separate letters. Ex: ത്ത is displaying as തത.