# Malayam in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am tried to show malayalam in android webview.
I am preparing an html and apply thoolika unicode font.Now i want to show if html content have english alphabets then show it in english.

How can i check whether an html string contains english alphabets in its body?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611578/webview-malayalam-unicode-complex-combined-letters

Comment: Yes.But it is not useful for my application.