# Display Unicode Malayalam (A South Indian language) web page in android webview

Tags: android, unicode, webview, asciiencoding

How can I display  Unicode Malayalam (A South Indian language) in Android **Webview**, which is displaying content from a blog page contains  Malayalam unicode font.?
(**For example** http://www.mathrubhumi.com page will display Malayalam characters correctly in all android devices because of using their custom fonts, but [ml.wikipedia.org](http://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%AA%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B0%E0%B4%A7%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%A8_%E0%B4%A4%E0%B4%BE%E0%B5%BE) page will not display any content properly in some android devices because its using UTF-8 Malayalam Unicode.)

I successfully done displaying Malayalam text using Android **Textview** by converting Unicode to ASCII character with the help of  [Displaying Malayalam Unicode fonts in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026171/displaying-malayalam-unicode-fonts-in-android-webview/10720283#10720283).
A similar solution found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237821/how-to-embed-a-custom-font-to-android-app-webview?rq=1) , but its taking local html file as input but here in my case its fetching webpage from the Internet.

Is there any possible solution to display Malayalam by converting Unicode to ASCII character while loading webpage in webview from any malayalam blog..?

Nithin poyyil
mail:nithincv1@gmail.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611578/webview-malayalam-unicode-complex-combined-letters

Comment: @Vishal :Let me try and will come back with feedback.